# Pulling a Spesific Text of a Part of Website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new on web scraping and BeautifulSoup. I'm making a currency converter via using a [site](https://www.xe.com/). I use this code to pull currency rate:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from_ = input("WHICH CURRENCY DO YOU WANT TO CONVERT: ").upper()
to = input("WHICH CURRENCY DO YOU WANT TO CONVERT TO: ").upper()

url = requests.get(f'https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From={from_}&To={to}').text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

currency = soup.find('p', class_ = 'result__BigRate-sc-1bsijpp-1 iGrAod').getText()

print(currency)
```

This is okay but it returns a full of text (e.g. 0.84311378 Euros). I want to pull only numbers that marked with red in picture:[image]

Comment: Do you need "Euros"?

Comment: No, I need just "0.84" but it returns "0.84311378 Euros" when i run my code on above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the number would always be the first element of this tag.An easy way could be :

```
currency_tag = soup.find('p', class_ = 'result__BigRate-sc-1bsijpp-1 iGrAod')

print(next(iter(currency_tag)))
```

And result:

```
0.84
```

Comment: Dude can you tell me why we used next and iter functions for do that? I didn't understand.

Comment: @statist31 `iter` to make it iterable, and do `next` to get the first element.If you call `next(currency_tag)` directly, it would raise exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.contents` and get the first item from it.

```
currency = soup.find('p', class_ = 'result__BigRate-sc-1bsijpp-1 iGrAod').contents
print(currency[0].strip())
```

```
0.84
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the string you highlighted in the picture represents the first three characters of the resulted price.

This means that any time you try to convert some type of currency to another one, the numbers marked with red will always represent a string with a length equal to 3.

We can pull the information you need by getting a substring of the paragraph’s text. Just replace the last line you provided with:

```
print(currency[0:4])
```

This will always return a string containing exactly the characters you are looking for.